# Set new variables values to be used with default mixin in SASS

Tags: variables, sass, zurb-foundation, overriding, mixins

I have this default SASS mixin (only a part of actually) from Foundation 6 ``_buttons.scss``` source file:

```
/// Margin around buttons.
/// @type List
$button-margin: 0 0 $global-margin 0 !default;

@mixin button-base {
  @include disable-mouse-outline;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: $button-margin;
}
```

As you can see, there are no parameters attached directly to it:

```
@mixin button-base($button-margin) { ... }
```

...but it uses several variables (like `$button-margin`) that are set outside of it.

What I'd like to do is to make use of this default mixin for a single button in my website that will have a specific `$button-margin` value.

So far, those solutions didn't work :

```
// 1.
@include button-base($button-margin: 0);

// 2.
@mixin extended-button-base {
  $button-margin: 0;
  @include button-base;
}
@include extended-button-base;

// 3.
@mixin button-base {
  $button-margin: 0;
}
@include button-base();
```

Any idea on how to achive this without having to override the whole mixin ?
Because if I override the whole mixin with including the new variable value, it works ...

```
@mixin button-base {
  $button-margin: 0;

  @include disable-mouse-outline;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: $button-margin;

  @if (type-of($button-padding) == 'map') {
    @each $size, $padding in $button-padding {
      @include breakpoint($size) {
        padding: $padding;
      }
    }
  }
  @else {
    padding: $button-padding;
  }

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: $button-radius;
  transition: $button-transition;

  font-size: map-get($button-sizes, default);
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@button-base;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is basically overriding the styles mixin each time you call it like this

```
@mixin button-base {
  @include disable-mouse-outline;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: $button-margin;
}

.class {
    @include button-base;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or you need to override the mixin once as you said and it will work. As well, you can simply override the $button margin by the variable you want